# How to access members of the matrix passed to a MEX function?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2010, matrix, mex

I'm writing a program that involves with finding the real roots of quadratic and cubic polynomials and since the `roots` function in MATLAB is for polynomials with general degree and computationally heavy, I've chosen such function from the [GSL Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) and I want to MEX it and use it in MATLAB. Here's the code:

```
/*
 * mx_solve_quadratic.cpp
 *
 * Solves for real roots of the standard quadratic equation
 *
 * The calling syntax is:
 *
 *      rootsMatrix = mx_solve_quadratic(coefficientsMatrix)
 *
 * This is a MEX file for MATLAB.
*/

#include <config.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

int gsl_poly_solve_quadratic (double , double , double , double *, double *)

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double a; /* coefficient for x^2 */
  double b; /* coefficient for x */
  double c; /* coefficient for 1 */
  double *x0 /* pointer to the smaller root */
  double *x1 /* pointer to the bigger root */
  mxGetData(prhs[0])
}


int gsl_poly_solve_quadratic (double a, double b, double c, double *x0, double *x1)
{
  if (a == 0) /* Handle linear case */
    {
      if (b == 0)
        {
          return 0;
        }
      else
        {
          *x0 = -c / b;
          return 1;
        };
    }

  {
    double disc = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if (disc > 0)
      {
        if (b == 0)
          {
            double r = sqrt (-c / a);
            *x0 = -r;
            *x1 =  r;
          }
        else
          {
            double sgnb = (b > 0 ? 1 : -1);
            double temp = -0.5 * (b + sgnb * sqrt (disc));
            double r1 = temp / a ;
            double r2 = c / temp ;

            if (r1 < r2) 
              {
                *x0 = r1 ;
                *x1 = r2 ;
              } 
            else 
              {
                *x0 = r2 ;
                  *x1 = r1 ;
              }
          }
        return 2;
      }
    else if (disc == 0) 
      {
        *x0 = -0.5 * b / a ;
        *x1 = -0.5 * b / a ;
        return 2 ;
      }
    else
      {
        return 0;
      }
  }
}
```

since a matrix of type single is passed to the MEX function, `prhs` is an mxArray with just one member and that is a matrix with 3 members.
I get this matrix by `mxGetData(prhs[0])`, but I don't know how to access members inside the matrix and get `a`,`b`,`c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply

```
 x0=mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
```

`mxGetPr` returns `double` pointer.

Then you can access to the member of `x0` by

```
 a=x0[0];
 b=x0[1];
 c=x0[2];
```

If your data type is different from `double`, you can use

```
 type variable = (type *) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
```